# Почему вылетает код, когда нет ответа с запроса requests get?

Tags: python, for

Есть код, который пингует сервера, и те, что отвечают на пинг - идет запрос через API.
Написал цикл:

```
def NoStatsToday():
for x in Online:
    url = 'http://' + x + ':8200/api/v1/detection_storage/get_detections_stat?datetime_start=' + today + 'T00:00:00%2B05:00&datetime_end=' + today + 'T23:59:59%2B05:00'
    response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
    forparse = response.json()
    all_detections = (forparse["statistic"]['all_detections'])
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
    except ConnectionError:
        print(x + ' Нет подключение к порту 8200')
    else:
        if all_detections != 0:
            print(x + ' Есть статистика')
        else:
            print(x + ' Нет статистики')
            nostatsfile.write(x + pingfile.write(url + now))
```

Если порт 8200 недоступен, по идее должно писать

```
except ConnectionError:
        print(x + ' Нет подключение к порту 8200')
```

Внес исправления, как посоветовал CrazyElf, если я правильно понял, имелось ввиду так:

```
def NoStatsToday():
    for x in Online:
        url = 'http://' + x + ':8200/api/v1/detection_storage/get_detections_stat?datetime_start=' + today + 'T00:00:00%2B05:00&datetime_end=' + today + 'T23:59:59%2B05:00'
        try:
            response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
            forparse = response.json()
            all_detections = (forparse["statistic"]['all_detections'])
            if all_detections != 0:
                print(x + ' Есть статистика')
            else:
                print(x + ' Нет статистики')
                nostatsfile.write(x + pingfile.write(url + now))
        except ConnectionError:
            print(x + ' Нет подключения к порту 8200')
```

Вроде сейчас не вылетает, прошу знающих проверить, остались ли еще какие то ошибки, из-за которых может неправильно отражаться данные или вылетать код ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так всё нужно в `try` внести, чтобы `except` сработал:

```py
    url = 'http://' + x + ':8200/api/v1/detection_storage/get_detections_stat?datetime_start=' + today + 'T00:00:00%2B05:00&datetime_end=' + today + 'T23:59:59%2B05:00'
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
        forparse = response.json()
        all_detections = (forparse["statistic"]['all_detections'])
    except ConnectionError:
        print(x + ' Нет подключение к порту 8200')
```

К чему у вас `else` относится я вообще не очень понял. К `for`? В любом случае вам нужно сделать какую-то инициализацию `all_detections` до цикла, иначе, если не будет ни одного успешного действия, у вас код упадёт на строке `if all_detections != 0:`

Comment: Я так понимаю, что except ConnectionError не дает прерваться программе при ошибке, и если ошибка есть - то пишет, что нет подключения к порту, дальше проверка if all_detections !=0:, значит есть статистика, а если 0, то нет статистики. Как можно инициализировать all_detections до цикла?

Comment: Ну, присвоить этой переменной хоть какое-то значение, например 0